# show Contact Photo from PIM list on screen in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, contacts, pim

I am working on a PIM contact list application in blackberry, in which I need to show complete detail information of all contacts one by one on screen.
Name:
Lastname:
Mobile:
Work:
Home:
**Photo:**

I know how to get all other information, but getting confused in showing photo of the Contact.
Please let me know, if you have any suggestion or any snippet for this task.:)
thanx in advance..!!!